# Connecting to RabbitMQ via hostname/ip (using NServiceBus)

Tags: rabbitmq, connection-string, nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus (5.x) with RabbitMQ (3.6) as the transport. This connection string works:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="NServiceBus/Transport"
     connectionString="host=localhost;username=****;password=***;RequestedHeartbeat=600;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But on the same server (where RabbitMQ server is installed), using host name or IP doesn't work:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="NServiceBus/Transport"
     connectionString="host=myServerPC;username=****;password=***;RequestedHeartbeat=600;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I get this error:

```
2016-04-04 14:37:45.370 ERROR NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ.RabbitMqConnectionManager Failed to connect to Broker: 'myServerPC', Port: 5672 VHost: '/'. ExceptionMessage: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'
```

I have tried the following:

1. Created my own admin user (not guest) and verified it by logging into the RabbitMQ Management UI. Works from remote machine too. All using myServerPC.
2. Installed license for NServicebus using Service Insight -> Register.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably this is because your RabbitMq instance only listens on `localhost`. Check the configuration for `RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS`, it should be empty or contain your host external ip address also. If it is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, you can only use your loopback address to connect to RabbitMq.